# octave daemon from php class file

Tags: php, symfony, octave, daemon

invoking php from a plain php file works fine but fails if the invocation is from a php file containing a class. Any solution?

```
require_once "/demo/src/AppBundle/Controller/Octave_lib.php";
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        ***$octave=new Octave(false);***
```

results in "139 command did not run successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume the reason is because of namespaces.

As you are in the `AppBundle\Controller` namespace when you use `new Octave` it will look for that class in the same namespace (`AppBundle\Controller\Octave`) which i will not find and, so, trigger an error.

You have 2 options..

Add a "use" and then continue doing things as you are...

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Octave;

class DefaultController extends Controller
```

or add a `\` to show that the class is in the global namespace...

```
$octave = new \Octave(false);
```

Comment: Great & thanks! I had to copy a folder named 'classes' into the AppBundle/Controller folder and do the "use Octave" to make it work

Comment: Everything in the src directory gets autoloaded so you could place them in there and it should work too. If you didn't want to muddy up the `AppBundle/Controller` directory.

Comment: For now i have placed the Octave files in AppBundle/Controller folder itself. created a Model.php file with a class called Model. a function in it returns $sum. the namespace is set to AppBundle\Controller. In the controller, i say include("Model.php"); use Model; and then $model=new Model(); crashes the server. why?